# Where in hovot halevavot does the author mention the benefits of work?

Tags: mussar-ethics, hovot-halevavot

I heard in a shiur that work is a bracha that prevents one from sin and allows one to be tested. In which chapter can I find this content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're referring to the fourth *sha'ar*, [*Sha'ar HaBitachon*, third chapter](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hovot/4-2.htm#3) (starts at "מדוע האדם צריך לטרוח בעבודה?‏").

[In English](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=380#ch3) (starts at "Why man must work for a livelihood").

Comment: Including your own summary of the salient points would improve this answer.